# Work browser certificate controls access to google cloud?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

To access Google Cloud at our company we had to install a browser certificate into chrome. Or at least to make the project visible.

Does anyone know what feature this is and where I can learn more about it?

Comment: Were you trying to access console.cloud.google.com? I have accessed Google Cloud from multiple devices, I never had to install a browser certificate into chrome. What kind of certificate you install?